# How to access data from grandparent in apollo graphql server?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, resolver

I am trying to access data from grandparent in a grandchild resolver. How do I achieve this?

```
{
    field1
    field2 {
        child1 {
            grandchild1
        }
    }
}
```

I want to access field1 in grandchild1. How to go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can directly pass field2 object as the parent arg of grandchild1.

```
const resolvers = {
    Query : {
        field2      : {return field2 obj}
    },
    Field2: {
        child1      : {return field2 obj}
    },
    Child1: {
        grandchild1 : {access field2 values return grandchild1}
    }
  }
```